# Identificação de espaço em arquivo TXT asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

boa noite, não estou conseguindo exibir quebra de linha que vem do meu arquivo TXT, tenho um arquivo TXT com 5 frases, porem quando coloco para exibir ná pagina default por um literal carrega o arquivo txt porem as frases são exibidas sem quebra de linha tudo junto, gostaria dessa ajuda, o codigo :

```
string[] linhas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\aless\Desktop\txt\frases.txt");


    foreach (string line in linhas)
    {

        LiteralTXT.Text +=  line;


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É simples, basta você adicionar os caracteres de quebra de linha, `"\r\n"`, antes de cada item do `foreach`, segue código:

```
string[] linhas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\aless\Desktop\txt\frases.txt");

foreach (string line in linhas)
{
    LiteralTXT.Text += $"\r\n{line}";
}
```

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar o <br> ? Já que é web ?

Comment: sim eu sei o <br> ele identifica aonde tem a quebra de linha, mas meu coordenador quer que identifique o espaçamento, eu testei sua solução continuou junto.